# Getting IAttributeSet From View Inflation Process

Tags: android, xamarin, attributes, mvvmcross, inflate

I'm working on a project that relies on the user adding a custom attribute to their Android layout elements. Just like MvvmCross' `app:MvxBind`. There are no custom view classes as the idea is that the user can use the normal Android views.

The problem is that in order to get the value of this tag I need to get the IAttributeSet that is used during the view inflation process and I can't find a method of doing so that suits my needs.

I have a working example using `LayoutInflater.IFactory` however, this requires me to set my own LayoutInflater/factory which, if the user is using a library such as MvvmCross, causes problems as only one factory can be set at once.

I'm looking for a way that I can get the `IAttributeSet` object whenever a view is inflated to check for my attribute that doesn't interfere with the standard LayoutInflater or LayoutInflater's from other libraries. Or if there is any way to get my attribute after the view has been inflated.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

I want to be able to get the value of `MyAttribute` from a view without subclassing views or creating custom views. This is easily accomplished with `LayoutInflater.IFactory` but this method interferes with libraries such as MvvmCross.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:MyAttribute="My attribute value" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to figure this out.

### Non-MvvmCross Solution

I stumbled across an article called "Layout Inflater: Friend or Foe?". I think [this is the link](https://academy.realm.io/posts/layoutinflater-droid-kaigi-2017-jenx/) but at the time of posting this answer it isn't working.

The author did an amazing talk on LayoutInflater and how he changed the Android LayoutInflater process so that he could intercept it for his library [Calligraphy](https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy). The resulting solution is called [ViewPump](https://github.com/InflationX/ViewPump) and it's written in Kotlin.

I have written the ViewPump library in Xamarin for use with non-MvvmCross projects: https://github.com/lewisbennett/viewpump.

### MvvmCross Solution

MvvmCross uses a solution based on InflationX' ViewPump to do its binding and we can access it by first creating the below classes:

```
public class BindingBuilder : MvxAndroidBindingBuilder
{
    protected override IMvxAndroidViewBinderFactory CreateAndroidViewBinderFactory()
    {
        return new ViewBinderFactory();
    }
}

public class ViewBinderFactory : IMvxAndroidViewBinderFactory
{
    public IMvxAndroidViewBinder Create(object source)
    {
        return new ViewBinder(source);
    }
}

public class ViewBinder : MvxAndroidViewBinder
{
    public override void BindView(View view, Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
    {
        base.BindView(view, context, attrs);

        // Do your intercepting here.
    }

    public ViewBinder(object source)
        : base(source)
    {
    }
}
```

Then in your `MvxAndroidSetup` or `MvxAppCompatSetup` class add the following:

```
protected override MvxBindingBuilder CreateBindingBuilder()
{
    return new BindingBuilder();
}
```

Done! I hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Please refer to the following：

you could create a custom view and define its attribute in `attrs.xml` and when it is created from an XML layout, all of the attributes in the XML tag are read from the resource bundle and passed into the view’s constructor as an `IAttributeSet`

for example,here is a custom view named **IconView**

```
public class IconView : View
{
}
```

define some attributes in `attrs.xml`(**Resources/values/attrs.xml**)

```
<declare-styleable name="IconView">
  <attr name="bg_color" format="color" />
  <attr name="src" format="integer" />
  <attr name="showIconLabel" format="boolean" />
  <attr name="iconLabelTextColor" format="color" />
  <attr name="iconLabelText" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

then we could process the attributes in the view constructor  when it is created (here define an Initialize method):

```
public IconView(Context context) : base(context)
{
  Initialize(context);
}

public IconView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
{
  Initialize(context, attrs);
}

private void Initialize(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs = null)
{
  if (attrs != null)
  {
    // Contains the values set for the styleable attributes you declared in your attrs.xml
    var array = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs, Resource.Styleable.IconView, 0, 0);

    iconBackgroundColor = array.GetColor(Resource.Styleable.IconView_bg_color, Color.Gray);
    iconLabelTextColor = array.GetColor(Resource.Styleable.IconView_iconLabelTextColor, Color.ParseColor("#D9000000"));
    _labelText = array.GetString(Resource.Styleable.IconView_iconLabelText);
    _showIconLabel = array.GetBoolean(Resource.Styleable.IconView_showIconLabel, false);

    var iconResId = array.GetResourceId(Resource.Styleable.IconView_src, 0);
    if (iconResId != 0) // If the user actually set a drawable
        _icon = AppCompatDrawableManager.Get().GetDrawable(context, iconResId);

    // If the users sets text for the icon without setting the showIconLabel attr to true
    // set it to true for the user anyways
    if (_labelText != null) 
        _showIconLabel = true;

    // Very important to recycle the array after use
    array.Recycle();
  }

     ...
}
```

You can refer to it for more details [make custom view](https://medium.com/@mclint_/how-to-make-a-custom-view-in-xamarin-android-3d2dcb391936)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm fully aware of the constructor where you can access the `IAttributeSet` object but this would require creating custom views which, as I mentioned, I don't want to have to do. I've updated the question with an example of what I want to achieve.

Comment: It seems impossible，if you want to add your custom attribute to the native control,you should create a custom control which extends the native control,and add the attributes like above